# CMake and Flex/Bison

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, bison, flex-lexer

I am converting my build system from configure/make to a cmake system

The system has some autogenerated files, from bison/flex. The original makefile commands are:

```
bison --defines=tokens.h --output=parser.cpp parser.y
flex --outfile=scanner.cpp scanner.l
```

I came across [this ancient link](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2002-September/003028.html) which seems to explain how to do it, but when i run cmake with the following custom commands, nothing appears to happen (no error messages, no file generation)

```
FIND_PACKAGE(BISON REQUIRED)
IF(BISON_FOUND)
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
      SOURCE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rcdgen/parser.y
      COMMAND ${BISON_EXECUTABLE}
      ARGS --defines=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rcdgen/tokens.h
           -o ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rcdgen/parser.cpp
           ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rcdgen/parser.y
      COMMENT "Generating parser.cpp"
      OUTPUT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rcdgen/parser.cpp
    )
ENDIF(BISON_FOUND)

FIND_PACKAGE(FLEX REQUIRED)
IF(FLEX_FOUND)
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
      SOURCE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rcdgen/scanner.l
      COMMAND ${FLEX_EXECUTABLE}
      ARGS -o${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rcdgen/parser.cpp
           ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rcdgen/scanner.l
      COMMENT "Generating scanner.cpp"
      OUTPUT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rcdgen/scanner.cpp
    )
ENDIF(FLEX_FOUND)
```

I am new to cmake, so it's a bit confusing to me. Does anyone have any idea what a working custom_command would be?

Comment: Can you also post the part of the CMakeList which uses the generated files?

Comment: Please be aware of tagging.  Flex-lexer is for the lexical analyzer; the flex tag is for the Adobe/Apache UI Framework.

Comment: sorry, 'flex' is what was suggested to me automatically, i didn't think to check the description

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The new hotness for bison usage is actually documented in [FindBison](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBISON.html) So for a simple parser project:

```
find_package(BISON)
BISON_TARGET(MyParser parser.y ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.cpp
             DEFINES_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.h)
add_executable(Foo main.cpp ${BISON_MyParser_OUTPUTS})
```

is what you'd do. Likewise for [Flex](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindFLEX.html).

Comment: Does not work on older version Flex version should be 2.5.5 or greater for this. Reason are the passed parameter by these functions.

Comment: When using this command, how can the Bison-generated header be used in the code? Neither `#include "parser.hpp` nor `#include "parser.tab.hpp"` work for me...

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović According to the Cmake documentation a header will be made and its filename will be defined by a certain macro. I don't know why it is done that way: Obviously you want to have the name in your code.

Answer (score 13):

The format of your [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command)s is not quite right, but they appear to be almost correct.  There are two versions of `add_custom_command`, and the one you want is the one which produces an output file (the parts inside square brackets are optional):

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT output1 [output2 ...]
                   COMMAND command1 [ARGS] [args1...]
                   [COMMAND command2 [ARGS] [args2...] ...]
                   [MAIN_DEPENDENCY depend]
                   [DEPENDS [depends...]]
                   [IMPLICIT_DEPENDS <lang1> depend1
                                    [<lang2> depend2] ...]
                   [WORKING_DIRECTORY dir]
                   [COMMENT comment] [VERBATIM] [APPEND])
```

The idea is that the custom command only executes if the file specified as the `OUTPUT` of this command is used as an input elsewhere in the same CMakeLists.txt (e.g. in an `add_library` or `add_executable` call).

The custom command therefore will only run at build time (i.e. when you run `make`), not at configure time (when you run CMake), and only if you're building a target which directly or indirectly needs the `OUTPUT` file.

To fix your commands, I think the following should work (untested):

```
FIND_PACKAGE(BISON REQUIRED)
SET(BisonOutput ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rcdgen/parser.cpp)
IF(BISON_FOUND)
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
      OUTPUT ${BisonOutput}
      COMMAND ${BISON_EXECUTABLE}
              --defines=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rcdgen/tokens.h
              --output=${BisonOutput}
              ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rcdgen/parser.y
      COMMENT "Generating parser.cpp"
    )
ENDIF()

FIND_PACKAGE(FLEX REQUIRED)
SET(FlexOutput ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rcdgen/scanner.cpp)
IF(FLEX_FOUND)
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
      OUTPUT ${FlexOutput}
      COMMAND ${FLEX_EXECUTABLE}
              --outfile=${FlexOutput}
              ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rcdgen/scanner.l
      COMMENT "Generating scanner.cpp"
    )
ENDIF()

ADD_LIBRARY(MyLib ${BisonOutput} ${FlexOutput})
```

Comment: This looks good, though i'm not sure what the add_library is for, could you elaborate?

Comment: @LordAro - sorry, I could have made that a bit clearer.  I was just trying to give an example of actually using the output files as inputs to another command.  I don't expect you actually have a library called "MyLib" or that any target uses just these 2 files.  I imagine these files will be 2 of many which comprise a lib/exe in your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: ok, that's what i suspected, and, it seems to work :)

Thanks very much

Comment: The new hotness for bison usage is actually documented at [cmake.org](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#module:FindBISON) So `bison_target(parser fl.ypp fl.tab.cpp)
add_executable(fl ${BISON_parser_OUTPUTS})` is what you'd do. Likewise for Flex.

Comment: `scanner.l` `parser.h` and `parser.tab.h` should be added as `DEPENDS` on the custom command as to regenerate the parser/lexer whenever the `.l` and `.y` files are modified. Parser only depends on `parser.y` but the lexer depends on both `scanner.l` and whatever header bison generates, usually `parser.tab.h`